# in class or in the class?

Tags: definite-article

I'm wondering whether the definite article is necessary in the following:

> John is such a dark horse. Who would have thought the shy boy in (the) class would become the CEO of a multinational business?

Comment: 'In class' points to the general classroom situation obtaining. 'In the class' points to the group of children involved. You can choose which you want, but  I'd rephrase the former to '... the boy who was so shy in class ...'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The understanding (or, at least, my understanding) of the sentence is that "class" is the children in a room at school.

In this situation, the definite article is needed.

Overall, I would prefer to use "of" instead of "in":

> ... the shy boy **of** the class ...

Or, in a different context, it could be:

> ... **a** shy boy **in** the class ...

Comment: Do you say "the shyest boy in the class" or "the shyest boy of the class"?

Answer (score -3):

I'd say, when you speak you use "in house" but if you write a text you use "in the house" but I'm not sure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/207479)